# python dict sub list append

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dict:

```
D = {'KEY-2': ['KEY-3.1', 'KEY-3.2']}
```

I want to change it:

```
D['KEY-2'] = dict.fromkeys(D.pop('KEY-2'),[])
>>> D
{'KEY-2': {'KEY-3.1': [], 'KEY-3.2': []}}
```

And append line to one of key subdict

```
D['KEY-2']['KEY-3.1'].append('line')
```

And I get:

```
>>> D
{'KEY-2': {'KEY-3.1': ['line'], 'KEY-3.2': ['line']}}
```

Why? What can I add line to only list `D['KEY-2']['KEY-3.2']`?

Comment: `dict.fromkeys()` does not make copies.

Comment: Use `D['KEY-2'] = {k: [] for k in D.pop('KEY-2')}`.

Comment: This might be a better dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174723/dictionary-creation-with-fromkeys-and-mutable-objects-a-surprise