# python dictionary: how does appending of items work?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I want to create a dictionary where the keys are string and the values are the lists. Initially, all lists are empty. Then I want to append an int to a specific list using "append()." The result: the int is appended to ALL list in my dictionary.

```
d = ['a', 'b', 'c']
my_d = dict.fromkeys(d, [])
my_d['a'].append(4)
print(my_d)

{'a': [4], 'b': [4], 'c': [4]}
```

I want it to be :

```
{'a': [4], 'b': [], 'c': []}
```

since I appended 4 to my_d['a'] only

Comment: Your values are the same reference. Do something like `{k: [] for k in d}`

Comment: Another option is `my_d = {}`, then create new lists when you need them with `my_d.setdefault('a', []).append(4)`. That will create a fresh empty list each time. Or use `collections.defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: While I completely stand by the dupe hammer, I added an answer to the duplicate question that is a bit more tailored to your needs. See option #3  in particular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51678197/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist I see you aren't a fan of `.setdefault` :)

Comment: @PM2Ring. I am, actually. I have never used defaultdict myself in the wild. I'll add something to the answer about that.

Comment: @PM2Ring. I've added a note. I don't think `setdefault` is ideal in this case.